# Difference btw PERFORM_PLAYBACK_IN_INTERACTIVE_MODE and INTERACTIVE options in RFT

Tags: interactive, rft

IOptionName interface provides these 2 fields, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are essentially the same but they correspond to the two different places from where user can set  the interactive mode.
One place where we could set the Interative mode is in the
 **Window->Preferences->FunctionalTest->Playback**   .
The flag : IOptionName.PERFORM_PLAYBACK_IN_INTERACTIVE_MODE  is for this preference.

The second place to set the Interactive mode is the Specify Playback Options" page which comes when after clicking Play/Run button for a script if we click "Next" in the Select Log page.

The flag: IOptionName.INTERACTIVE    is for this preference.

We can Test both these flags  (by checking/unchecking the checkboxes  in the two places mentioned above) and playing back a script that has following code:

```
 System.out.println(OptionManager.getBoolean(IOptionName.PERFORM_PLAYBACK_IN_INTERACTIVE_MODE));
 System.out.println(OptionManager.getBoolean(IOptionName.INTERACTIVE));
```